# Requiring authentication after credentials change

Tags: javascript, security, authentication

Is it a bad pattern or a best practice. Say a user has successfully changed his password after "Forgotten password". Do I need to redirect him to the login page and prompt him to log-in or should I automatically log him in to the application?

If either, why?

Answer (score 1):

I can't imagine any security advantage of requiring him to login after he successfully changed password with forgotten password.  However, there may be usability benefits such as: (1) reinforcing in the user's memory what their new password is, and (2) allowing their browser to store the new password so that they do not need to type it in next time they login from that browser.

It is fairly common to redirect the user to login with that new password.

Answer (score 0):

The [OWASP recommendation](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Forgot_Password_Cheat_Sheet) is actually:

> Whenever a successful password reset occurs, the session should be
>   invalidated and the user redirected to the login page.

For more info see [this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/105126/8340):

> Password reset functionality is often used when a user wishes to
>   secure their account.
>
> By invalidating all existing sessions upon password reset, the system
>   is making sure that only the person with the new password can login.
>
> Say, for example, an attacker that has gained access to the account
>   using the old password is logged in. Resetting all sessions will log
>   the attacker out.

This might also be used in a forgotten password scenario if the attacker has managed to update the user's password to prevent login, but for some reason hasn't updated the email to one not under the control of the real user. This could be because updating the email address causes an alert to go to the old address, and the attacker doesn't want to risk creating any unnecessary noise (although it is also good practice to send an email to the registered user upon any password change).

Actual redirection and logout isn't really necessary though. This simply needs the session identifier of the current session to be rotated, and the session identifiers of all other sessions to be revoked. This should prevent access by any attacker riding an existing session. There are a couple of advantages though as detailed in [TheGreatContini's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36075483/413180).